# Error in Axios API Post request in Nodejs

Tags: node.js, express, axios, paystack

I am trying to make an API call to `Paystack` API. I am using Axios package for `node.js`. I can't seems to get it to work.

Here is my code:

```
  const response = await axios({
    method: 'post',
    url:'https://api.paystack.co/transaction/initialize',
    data: paymentDetails,
    headers : {
        Authorization: 'mysecretKey',
          'content-type': 'application/json',
          'cache-control': 'no-cache'
      },
})
return res.json(response)
```

On postman, I simply provided the `payment details via the body` as requested by Paystack:

```
"id": 1,
"username": "kings",
"email": "emailaddress",
"amount": 100
```

I am getting this error: `AxiosError: Request failed with status code 401`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have the `Authorization` wrong.

Try this:

```
const response = await axios({
    method: 'post',
    url:'https://api.paystack.co/transaction/initialize',
    data: paymentDetails,
    headers : {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${mysecretKey}`,
          'content-type': 'application/json',
          'cache-control': 'no-cache'
      },
})
return res.json(response)
```

Notice the `Authorization: Bearer {secret}`

https://paystack.com/docs/api/#authentication

Comment: Thank you. This solved it. I didnt include 'Bearer' to the 'Authorization'. Thank you very much